# rails which is best place to save static html files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have to save some html files and wanted to load them for some requirement.
Currently i am placing that files in public folder.
Also, i don't want to save it outside `(amazon s3 etc)` the rails application for some good reason.
Please let me know which is idea way to do such functionality in Rails.
I am using Rails 3.2.21

Answer (score 2):

Actually I think `/public` is not a bad place for static html files. As long as you don't need any processing this should work well.

See [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-directory-structure.htm):

> public − Like the public directory for a web server, this directory
>   has web files that don't change, such as JavaScript files
>   (public/javascripts), graphics (public/images), stylesheets
>   (public/stylesheets), and HTML files (public).